# How to close a top safari browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to close a *Safari* browser through:

```
window.navigate("javascript:top.close()");
```

or

```
function closeBrowser(){
    top.close();
}
```

They work fine in *IE*, but are not in *Safari*.

Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "top" the current "tab" that is opened, you can't do that at all in javascript for chrome. There is a solution to close the browser in Firefox though

```
var answer = confirm("Do you wnat to close this window ?"); if (answer){
 netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserWrite');
 top.close(); 
} else{ stop; }
```

Comment: My goal is to close the main page from an iframe in Safari. I created a button on the main page and using "top.close" function, it works. But after I changed my iframe to next page, it doesn't work. Does anyone know about the privilege setting in Safari?